# Hash function which returns not just lowercase letters and numbers, but also symbols and uppercase letters

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, cryptography

All hash algorithms (sha1, md5 etc) seem to return string with lowercase letters and numbers. Are there any algorithms which also return symbols like `[ ] \ , !` etc. and uppercase letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical hash function (like MD5) produces bytes as output. These bytes are usually hex encoded so that they can be represented as text. However, there are other [binary-to-text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) encodings too.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to refer to the hexdecimal-ascii representation ("letters and numbers") of the hash. That's just a different way of saying "number", only with sixteen symbols instead of ten as in decimal or two in case of binary.

You can map the hash - which is just a number like any other - to any representation you want. You may, for example, base85-encode the hash which gives you a ascii-string like ">uD.RTpAKYo'+CT/5+Cei#DII?(E,9)oF*2M7/c~>", depending on the size of the hash.